# Copy from local Excel 2010 and paste formula to remote (Citrix server) Excel 2013 not working

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, citrix

I have Excel 2010 running on my local computer (Windows 7) and also another Excel 2013 running on a remote Citrix Server. When I copy a cell containing a formula from my local Excel 2010 and try to paste it to remote Excel 2013, it only pastes the value and not the formula. If I do paste special, it does not give me the formula option but rather the option to paste as picture, Bitmap,DIF, Unicode Text or Text. I want to be able to paste the formula. Is the problem occuring because Im copying from local and pasting to remote or is it the difference of Excel versions (2010 vs 2013). Are there any solutions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: My only solution is to tell you to copy the formula from the bar and paste that into the other.

Comment: Yeah but when I'm copying a big number of cell with different formulas in each, it's not ideal. Thx for your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Excel will only copy-paste that nicely (formulas, formatting, etc) between local Office applications. So when you try to copy from the one device to the other, it's forcing your cells down to a simple plaintext representation. For evidence of this, you could try pasting that same value into a simple text editor like Notepad - you'll see that the only data in your clipboard are the plaintext values, formatted with tabs and newlines to denote the cell positions.

But, we can get around this! Turn your spreadsheet over to "Formula View Mode" temporarily - you can toggle this on/off with CTRL+` (which is the "backtick" located under the escape button on a standard QWERTY keyboard). Now you'll see all the formulas in your cells instead of the values. If you copy cells, these formulas will be copied. Then you should be able to paste directly into the remote instance of Excel without any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixes my issue.